# VS Database Project Primary Key Name

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, database-project

I have a database project in Visual Studio 2015. I would like to name the primary key but it seems to ignore any attempts. Naming default constraints though does work.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Stock]
(
    [Id] INT CONSTRAINT [PK_Stock_Id] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [StockCode] NVARCHAR(6) NOT NULL, 
    [CreatedDate] DATETIME2 CONSTRAINT [DF_Stock_CreatedDate] DEFAULT sysutcdatetime() NOT NULL
)
GO
```

If you click on the primary key it even has a name property but it is readonly. I got it to create just the script rather than publish to SQL Server and it strips out the word constraint and name on the primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work for you:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Stock]
(
[Id] INT NOT NULL, 
[StockCode] NVARCHAR(6) NOT NULL, 
[CreatedDate] DATETIME2 NOT NULL
)
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Stock  ADD CONSTRAINT
DF_Stock_CreatedDate DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR CreatedDate
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Stock ADD CONSTRAINT
PK_Stock_Id PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
Id
)
GO
```

Comment: thanks, did think about doing it as separate step but thought there might be a nice in line solution. Visual Studio does actually pick up that bit of script properly and shows the name of the primary key in the interface. I don't think there is any need to change the default constraint from what i have.

Comment: PK and FK constraint definitions go after all of the Column definitions when doing in-line. If you leave it alone and add a PK using the GUI, it will put in a non-named PK constraint. You'll have to edit the SQL to add the name using CONSTRAINT pk_name PRIMARY KEY syntax if you want a name (which you really should have).

Answer (score 11):

I noticed the same behavior (this was in Visual Studio 2015 for me as well).

[image: vs2015-db-unnamed-constraint]

## GUI Option

I found that upon removing and then re-setting the primary key, the automatic name `PK_<tableName>` was given to the PK constraint.

1. right-click on the PK field and select "Remove Primary Key"

   - [see the `<unnamed>` PK constraint under the Keys node disappear]
2. right-click on that field again and select "Set Primary Key"

   - [see the PK constraint reappear under the Keys node, this time named]

I don't know if there is a way to make the constraint's name property directly editable in the GUI though. So, if you want more granular control over the name (i.e. a name not tied to the table name), script editing might be the only option.

(I'm clearly very late to this SO question, but perhaps this answer can be useful to others that might run across this later.)

Comment: I notice when I remove and set, then the script below changes to show an entry to create the PK_ named index, so you can easily edit it there.

Comment: Ugh! Spent way too much time on that.